# Running Laravel Envoy from Jenkins

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, deployment, laravel-envoy

I have a deployment script running from Envoy on a Laravel project.  The script is a heavily modified version of https://github.com/nickfan/envoy-deployscript.

Deployments are run locally to multiple servers and Envoy handles this well.  However, I have been asked to move deployments over to Jenkins.

Can I run the Envoy script from Jenkins or should I concentrate on rewriting the entire release deployment script?

Any wisdom is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you add envoy command to "Execute shell" under "Build", you will be able to run envoy script on Jenkins.